# Disable default silverlight context menu on rightclick

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, contextmenu, silverlight-5.0

I want to **remove the default context menu of SilverLight** (shows only one menu item "silverlight") **on Mouse Right click**.

I have tried the following ways.

1. I have tried this code.But it is not getting worked.

**code:**

```
<script>

document.getElementById('silverlightObjDiv').oncontextmenu = disableRightClick;

function disableRightClick(e) {

    if (!e) e = window.event;

    if (e.preventDefault) {

        e.preventDefault();

    } else {

        e.returnValue = false;
    }
}
</script>
```

2. I have tried to block on MouseRightButtonDown event. But by right clicking on datagrid, button etc silverlight pop up is coming up.

**Code:**

```
public MainPage()
{
    LayoutRoot.MouseRightButtonDown += (s, e) => { e.Handled = true; };
}
```

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: You should add your question to the content, not just to the headline

Answer (score 0):

You're nearly there. The context menu is displayed on MouseRightButton**Up**.

```
public MainPage()
{
    LayoutRoot.MouseRightButtonUp += (s, e) => { e.Handled = true; };
}
```